# How do I save a change in the Uniface 10 IDE?

Tags: ide, uniface

I would like to make a change in the Uniface 10 IDE. However, I can't find an item in the menu to save the change.
So I ask myself the question how can I save a change in Uniface?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the documentation of Uniface. It says the following "The Uniface IDE automatically saves modifications as you work, so you do not have to explicitly save development objects."

See: [Save New and Modified Objects](https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/Uniface/10/uniface/ide/_common/AutomaticSave.htm?TocPath=Uniface%20IDE%7CWorking%20with%20Development%20Objects%7C_____5)